# IPAM could not collect login event from Windows Server 2016 NPS

Tags: windows-server-2016, nps, ipam

We have one IPAM server ( installed on Windows server 2016 ) in my Network. We have 4 NPS servers. two of them are Windows server 2012R2 and other two are Windows Server 2016. IPAM server could collect login event from Windows Server 2012R2 NPS, but could not collect from Windows server 2016. As you know, windows server 2016 NPS does not support Network access protection so there is no event 6278 in Microsoft Windows security auditing. I wonder IPAM is looking for event 6278.

I want to know which event ID was checked from IPAM. Somebody could give me this information. I think the event ID that is checked in Windows Server 2016 is no longer available.

Any idea

Thanks in advance

Emin